# Compile Mat rows with template sequence (c++, Opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, barcode

My question is complicated:

I have Thresholded picture **image**. Than go through pixels:

```
for (i=0; i<image.rows; ++i)
    {
        pixel = image.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (j=0; j<image.cols; ++j)
        {
            int p = pixel[j];
```

And get **in line**, for example, next sequence:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 255 255 255 255;

I need count quantity of each value that same with current value `if (p == pixel[j++])` and get next look:

```
               13 6 10 4 3 4
```

where:

13 = quantity of 0 before pixel value change

6  = quantity of 255 value before pixel value change

10 = quantity of next 0 before pixel value change

4  = quantity of 255 value before pixel value change

3  = quantity of next 0 before pixel value change

4  = quantity of 255 value before pixel value change

etc....

I think to use next algorithm: check, is next pixel value of line same with current value. If "yes" - sum this value with next, if "no" = reset to zero and sum again before next value change.

I try to do something like next: `int x = x + pixel[j++];`, but something is not OK with result - need help!

Than I need to find template sequence in line:

In `13 6 10 4 3 4`

I want to minus current value with next: 13-6, 6-10, 10-4, 4-3, 3-4 and get result with positive or negative value. If "TRUE", for example - assign "1", if "FALSE" = assign "2", to get number, like

`1 2 1 1 2` (**result** line for my sample)

This is sequence that, as I think, will be constant in any image dimension.

Now I need find is there in this line, one of sequence templates?

For example, I have some unique templates:

```
1 2 2,  2 2 1, 1 1 1, 2 1 1
```

and I need find, what template meet in **result** line... It is `2 1 1` template. 
If there is match - write **variable** of founded template in list (I need get table of some **templates** that meet **in lines** from top to bottom of picture), if no match = go to next line.

Ask for your advises? 
Thank you that read to the end of question.

Comment: Nice description fo what you want to do, but what you have tried so far?

Comment: I ask for advises for Rows with tamplate compiling. Now I got 0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 sequence and problem to get sequence like 13 6 10 4 3 4 from my example. I understand algorithm, but have not enough knowledges.

Comment: Then it si Off-Topic for SO as -> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: Sorry, I don't ask for prepared code, just ask for global advises with realization.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that may help:

```
std::vector<int> getConsecutiveElementCount(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::vector<int> res;
    if (input.empty()) {
        return res;
    }
    int count = 0;
    auto last = input[0];
    for (const auto& elem : input) {
        if (elem == last) {
            ++count;
        } else {
            res.push_back(count);
            last = elem;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    res.push_back(count);
    return res;
}
```